# Rotate UIView and fill screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, webview, wkwebview

In my iOS app, I have to conditionally rotate a WKWebView and would like the WebView to fill the entire screen (minus the top toolbar). I'm able to rotate the WebView, but it doesn't seem to be filling the full screen.

This is what I currently have:

**initiating the WebView:**

```
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];

self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0];

width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];

[self.view addConstraint:height];
[self.view addConstraint:width];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Then in didFinishNavigation, I receive a response from the server which determines whether the WebView needs to be rotated:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    NSURLComponents *params = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:self.webView.URL resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
    NSArray *queryItems = params.queryItems;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name=%@", @"tree_width"];
    NSURLQueryItem *queryItem = [[queryItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
                                 firstObject];
    int tree_width = [queryItem.value intValue];

    if(tree_width > 10){
        // rotate WebView

        self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
        self.webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);   
    }
}
```

You can see that the WebView is not fully stretched (height-wise) to fit the screen (it should cover up the tableview behind it):

[image]

Comment: Did you try to put the frame code on the main thread?

Comment: how about adding the webView on UIWindow's subview (instead of adding it on self.view's subviews)?

Comment: u cannot change the frame while auto layout is on.Have look on it http://stackoverflow.com/a/25423850/3767017

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it because i've not tested it, but there is no need to change the frame before the transform since you set auto layout, remove the frame line and if it doesn't work you can reset the webview constraints right after transform by deleting the previous ones and creating new ones